# what happens if elastic 'coordinating and ingest' node goes down?

Tags: elasticsearch

assume an elasticsearch deployment with 2 zones for 'Hot data and Content' and a single zoned coordinating and ingest node;
if the coordinating node goes down, does the deployment continue to work, or is it down until the coordinating node either comes up or the deployment is modified to not use one (or is that behavior automated in such a case?) thanks. btw, this is talking about a scenario in elastic.co ; cloud elastic offering

I tried searching in their documentation but didn't see this discussed.

Comment: How many total nodes you have in each zone ? from that how many are ingest and coordinate node ?

Comment: 1 node per zone, so 2 total. the selection for coordinating/ingest node is separate, and you can select 1, 2 or 3 zones. currently, 1 zone is selected, - so 1 node.

Comment: You can check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-ha.html this document

Comment: its not discussed in the document, I posted the question here, so that if someone knows it'll be helpful for someone else ;)